# Bibliography Undesirably Shortens "Technical Report" to "Tech. Rep."

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I have the following entry in my bib file:

```
@techreport{Robbins1956AnEmpirical,
title       = {{An Empirical {Bayes} Approach to Statistics}},
author      = {Robbins, Herbert},
year        = {1956},
institution = {Columbia University}, 
address     = {New York City, United States}, }
```

And let's assume that this is the main .tex document I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

I cite \cite{Robbins1956AnEmpirical}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

Its output looks like this.

[image]

Instead of short-form "Tech. Rep." I would like it to say "Technical Report" so that it is consistent with the rest of the bibliography, is there a way to fix this. Or should I just suck it up and let it go.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: The solution here depends strongly on the bibliography/citation packages (`biblatex`, `cite`, `natbib`, ...) that you load and on the bibliography style (`\bibliographystyle` for BibTeX, the argument of the `style` option for `biblatex`). Please show us not only the relevant `.bib` entry, but also a short document that reproduces your bibliography/citation setup (ideally in MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: I have edited the question to provide better details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is defined in the `.bst` file you passed to `\bibliographystyle`, defined by the function

```
FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}{ "Tech. Rep." }
```

To change the short form, edit your `.bst` file and replace the previous line with

```
FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}{ "Technical Report" }
```

If this is the only entry you want to modify, you can add this field

```
type = {Technical Report}
```

to the bib entry. In your case:

```
@techreport{Robbins1956AnEmpirical,
title       = {{An Empirical {Bayes} Approach to Statistics}},
author      = {Robbins, Herbert},
year        = {1956},
institution = {Columbia University}, 
address     = {New York City, United States},
type        = {Technical Report}
}
```

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the OP is using a bibliography style that defines a BibTeX function called `bbl.techrep`. This assumption may or may not be appropriate. Let's find out if the OP weighs win with some relevant information.

Comment: Is there a more ad-hoc solution? I do not really want to mess with the default IEEEtran behavior. The rest of my references are all in long format (i.e. I write "in Proceeding of the..." instead of "in Proc. ..." and so on.) This is the only reference that disobeys, I don't know if I should try and change the citation style from "@techreport" to "@unpublished" or something. If there is a simpler ad-hoc solution, I would prefer that.

Comment: @Semzem Oh, I see. In that case, you can use the `type` field. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!